# Can we block ARP requests in wan router

Tags: arp

Can we block ARP requests in wan router? I cannot send ARP requests to anyone I think my isp blocked it.

I can't connect to other nodes in the LAN. When I inspected flow of packets using wireshark. I found something interesting when I tried to connect other node, my system sent ARP broadcast to everyone but I got no reply but the system is alive. I checked it manually it happens for all nodes is LAN. I thought ISP blocked ARP; is there any other case?

Answer (score 0):

1. No you cannot disable/block [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) on the WAN interface. if you did, your ISPs equipment could not discover and send frames to the systems MAC address. Also, if you have a Cable Modem or other DMARC device, the WAN side of your router is only the single line between the router and the modem, so even if you did send an ARP, there is only one host to recieve it, and it has already been mapped in the devices ARP table.
2. ARP is mostly a layer-2 protocol (although forward requests are a L3 packet, but they are not routed), so no setting on your WAN will affect anything on your LAN. ARP requests/replies do not cross routers, so they are isolated to the LAN they are sent on. Likewise an ARP on the segment between your router's WAN and the modem/dmarc device could not cross onto your LAN, or onto the ISPs network. If you are having trouble with a system on your LAN related to MAC-to-ip address resolution, then your ISP has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Please have a look at my [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1183548/block-arp-requests-or-broadcast-message-if-possible-from-a-specific-host-in-a), there I wanted to whitelist/blacklist some hosts within my subnet, not blocking any ARP request. Details provided in the question. Thanks